# How to see what changed in a sprint in greenhopper

Tags: jira, baseline, sprint, jira-agile

We use Greenhopper/Jira for planning our Sprints.

A coworker want to see the changes that happens during a sprint: what tasks got, done; What tasks got added or removed from the sprint.

Is there a nice way to do that?

The only think we came up so far is to export the sprint context at the start of the sprint and at the end and compare it.

Limitations of that approach are:

- If we forget to do such an export, we loose the capability to compare, since there is no way  to turn the time back.
- We have to juggle excel files or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to your Agile Board, switch to Report mode (press key "3"), select the "Sprint Report"   from report dropdown and right under select the sprint you want to get information about. This report shows all information you need to know about your sprint. At the top you will see the minified burndown chart, then list of completed issues and issues which were removed from sprint while you were working with it. Issues with asterisk are those which were added to a sprint after it's start. See the following link for more information https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Viewing+the+Sprint+Report